# My Regular Expression will not Match Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, conditional-statements

Can anyone tell me why, even when my alert shows that my regular expression strings match, the if statement is not triggered? I have sample code below. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div#primaryNavigation').find('a').each(function () {
        var pattern = /my-link1|my-link2|my-link3|my-link4/;
        var myWindow = window.location.pathname.match(pattern);
        var href = $(this).attr('href').match(pattern);
        alert('Show link and href until match: ' + myWindow + ' ' + href);
        if (myWindow == href) {
            //* Do Something *
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The return value from `.match()` is not a string, it's an array of strings. Arrays don't compare as equal when they happen to contain the same values.

Try

```
if (myWindow[0] == href[0]) { ... }
```

Probably should also verify that the return values aren't null too:

```
if (myWindow && href && myWindow[0] === href[0]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement fails for the same reason `[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` fails.  You need to compare the contents of each list, or more simply compare myWindow[0] == href[0].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var pattern =/(my-link1|my-link2|my-link3|my-link4)/;
```

Comment: @jAndy I believe mylink1 etc are placeholders